# In hex-based representation of memory addresses ,does changing the least significant bit by 2 mean an increase/decrease of 2 bytes or bits?

Tags: memory, stack, environment-variables, hex

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ cp a.out a
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./a SLEDLESS
SLEDLESS is at 0xbfffff4e
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ cp a.out bb
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./bb SLEDLESS
SLEDLESS is at 0xbfffff4c
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ cp a.out ccc
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./ccc SLEDLESS
SLEDLESS is at 0xbfffff4a
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./a.out SLEDLESS
SLEDLESS is at 0xbfffff46
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gdb -q
(gdb) p 0xbfffff4e - 0xbfffff46
$1 = 8
(gdb) quit
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $
```

He's basically making different files of different filename lengths to see how it will affect the memory of the environment variable SLEDLESS.

This is his explanation:

***As the preceding experiment shows, the length of the name of the execut-
ing program has an effect on the location of exported environment variables. 
The general trend seems to be a decrease of two bytes in the address of the 
environment variable for every single-byte increase in the length of the pro-
gram name. This holds true with the program name a.out, since the differ-
ence in length between the names a.out and a is four bytes, and the difference 
between the address 0xbfffff4e and 0xbfffff46 is eight bytes. This must mean 
the name of the executing program is also located on the stack somewhere, 
which is causing the shifting.***

Shouldn't the general trend be a decrease of 2 bits each time? And so all the other places he says bytes , they should be changed to bits?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the general trend be a decrease of 2 bits each time?

No. For one thing characters (i.e., bytes), integers, pointers, etc. are not stored at arbitrary bit offsets within a byte or word of memory.

Whether the address changes by one, two, four or eight bytes in this experiment depends both on the architecture (e.g., x86, x86_64, arm, ppc, etc.) and the language being used. Also, I can't tell from your question whether the addresses correspond to the `SLEDLESS` CLI argument (i.e., `argv[1]`) or whether the program is reporting the address returned by `getenv("SLEDLESS")` (I'm assuming this is a C program). That will also affect how the address changes.

Comment: so SLEDLESS is an environment variable and yes , it uses getenv.  I'm still a bit confused though as to why the difference between 0xbfffff4e and 0xbfffff4c is 2 bytes rather than 2 bits?